# permalink structure for single-{post-type}.php in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have tried many ways to display my custom post type as single-{post-type} and finally it works nicely once i used:

> 'rewrite'=> false,

before that, i used

> 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'custom-post-type' )

but never works for me. Don't know where i made mistake. Right now i should feel happy cos its working without any error. But have a small confusion for the permalink because its display:

> localhost/myblog/?news=breaking-news **instead of**: localhost/myblog/news/breaking-news

anyone please provide me some idea how to get link like:

> localhost/myblog/news/breaking-news

my permalink structure selected: > http//myblog/sample-post/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had it right the first time...

`'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'custom-post-type')`

If it's not working then try clearing your rewrite cache by going to Settings > Permalinks and clicking the save button.